# dust.js turn off HTML encoding globally

Tags: dust.js

Is there a way to turn off HTML encoding globally within dust.js? I trust my data enough to want to turn it off during rendering. Instead of having to add "|s" to every tag in every template file, being able to set it globally would be ideal.

If not, is there a way to use filtering with custom helpers? I created a @val helper, but have no way to apply the "|s" filter. According to the docs, the following should work:

`{@val filters="|s" /}`

But it doesn't work on its own, so I'm thinking some logic needs to be placed within the helper itself.

Comment: Still haven't found a solution to the second question, but for the first, I was able to globally remove auto-escaping by updating the "|h" filter to not escape:

dust.filters.h = function(value) { return value; };

I also added a new filter to replace it:

dust.filters.esc = function(value) { return dust.escapeHtml(value); };

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the little-documented `esc` pragma to apply a global context to a template block.

```
{
  "hello": "Hello & World"
}

{%esc:s}
  This applies |s to everything inside the pragma
  {hello} <-- will not escape the ampersand
{/esc}
```

---

For your second question, it depends on what your helper is doing. If your helper returns any sort of Chunk, via `Chunk.render` for example, you must apply filters manually. If your helper returns a value, that value will be passed through any `filters` that are present. Here are a couple examples: say you have a helper `{@val}` that simply returns anything passed to it as a `value`.

Returning a value from your helper means `filters` is respected:

```
dust.helpers.val = function(chunk, context, bodies, params) {
  return params.value;
};

{@val value="Hello & World" /} <-- Hello &amp; World
{@val value="Hello & World" filters="s" /} <-- Hello & World
```

Returning a chunk from your helper ignores `filters`:

```
dust.helpers.val = function(chunk, context, bodies, params) {
  return chunk.write(params.value);
};

{@val value="Hello & World" /} <-- Hello & World
```